# How to save the position of a dragged ImageView in Android?

Tags: android, layout, imageview

following situation:

I have a layout with some `ImageView`s on it. The user can drag them around. I also have a button to add some new `ImageView`s. When clicking it you get an overview where you can choose an image. Then the overview activity ends and you return to the fragment.

Now the problem:

Because the `Fragment` is initialized again when returning from the other activity, all positions of the `ImageView`s which I put in place before are lost.

Whats the best way to save the positions of the dragged `ImageView`s? get the margins of each and save them?
I have an SQLite DB running but I think it's an overkill to save the position of each `ImageView` there.

Comment: I don't think it is possible without saving the positions somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the question is would you like your app to remember the positions even in case of a restart?

If you do, you need to use some sort of persistent storage, such as a database, a `File` or `SharedPreferences`.

If not, just cache them in memory, in a `HashMap` for example.

To get the positions, you could do something like this in your `OnDragListener`:

```
public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {

    final int action = event.getAction();
    switch(action) {

        // ...

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
            float x = event.getX;
            float y = event.getY;

            savePosition(x, y);
            break;
    }
}
```